# navigation bar hidden for entire application permanently and it will not pop up when i swipe up from bottom

Tags: android, hide, navigationbar, android-windowmanager, android-immersive

will you please tell me how can I hide navigation bar for the entire application in my android device after launching my application. I don't need to popup navigation bar by swiping up from the bottom.

Comment: You cannot disable navigation bar popup because of security reason, user must have possibility to turn off your application

Comment: is there any possibility to hide my navigation bar and add any custom view which will not take the touch and place it in the bottom.I think if swipe up is not recognized then navigation pop-up will not come.

Comment: will you please give me how can I hide it in the entire application which is launching from my application